# Designing a Turing-machine which halts

Tags: turing-machines

I am asked to design a turing-machine (the oldschool way using states and an explicit delta-function). Requirement is: Input is epsilon (infinite number of "blank" symbols) on which the TM should halt, the used alphabet is {B, 0, 1} (with B being the "blank" symbol), and the maximum number of states is 5.

Goal is to find a solution which prints the biggest amount of "1"s as possible.

My idea: first print two "0"s (the maximum I can get out of 2 states), then replace every 0 with "1" and add another "1" to the string. If "B" is reached, also replace it.

Makes a total of six "1"s being output.

Maybe anyone got an idea how to get more?

**ADD**

Okay, credits go to Zane for this hint.

According to some google search and wikipedia reading, this is exactly what I'm/I was searching for: http://www.logique.jussieu.fr/~michel/ha.html#tm43

Comment: have you googled for this? Look out for something called the busy beaver.

Comment: If you found an answer to your problem, please *do not* edit your question. Please put the answer in the answers section below and then accept it. It is okay to answer your own question.